# Can I connect two laptops and record the 2nd laptop's display with the 1st laptop and ffmpeg?

Tags: debian, ffmpeg, xorg

I have two laptops; I would like to connect them and be able to record the display of the second laptop through the first laptop. Is this possible, and if so, how? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ffmpeg specifically:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -i :0 -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 18 -f h264 udp://192.168.0.1:8080
```

It is simpler to use VLC which has built in streaming:

```
cvlc screen:// :screen-fps=30 :screen-caching=100 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=http, mux=ts, dst=192.168.0.1:8080}'
```

If you are looking for a low/zero impact on the Source laptop's overall performance:

1. Add linux compatible video capture hardware on the Recorder laptop.
2. Mirror the Source laptop's display to whatever display shows up from the capture device.

You will be limited to whatever resolutions are reported by the Recorder attached capture device. Make sure your capture hardware can support the resolution and framerate you want. The Recorder laptop will also need to be able to handle it.

Other options for [streaming your display](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=debian+stream+desktop) (VLC/ffserver) to the Recorder device with varying levels of compression vs bandwidth consumption will have a direct impact on the Source device. For the lowest impact on the Source device you will want to stream with no compression/encoding at all. This will consume your network bandwidth though and is NOT a zero impact solution.

Any level of compression is basically recording on the Source laptop and then copying the record to the Recorder laptop to store it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SHawarden for information and answer!